# Can't create "hero walking" animation

Tags: html5, spritesheet, pixel-art

I'm creating a [Fez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fez_%28video_game%29)-based HTML5 Canvas game and animating my hero image using sprite sheets. The problem is that I can't create the animation of the hero walking, don't matter how much I try, the output is a weird animation that looks like the hero is just shaking its legs. Can someone help me? You don't need to create the sprite sheet for me if you don't want, just show me what's the correct leg position. I'll post the game link in a comment because I can't post more than two links.

Note that the "hero's legs" are compound by 3 pixels each, that are 2x up scaled.

**[Here is the sprite sheet:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU03Y.png)**

[image: spritesheet]

the walking animation is compound by the 6 first frames.

**EDIT: If you fall in the demonstration, open the console, type `localStorage.x = localStorage.y = 0;` and then reload the page immediately to return to the starting point.**

Comment: http://escherparkour.com/insanejs

Comment: I didn't see animation code in your source. I suppose the playback is inside the Fez engine (I don't know it), right? Or did I miss it..

Comment: While I haven't played Fez myself, a) the animation seems to be fine for me (IE11) and b) you shouldn't use other people's (or companies') art.

Comment: @Mario the art was made by me, but inspired on Fez.

Comment: @antont I didn't understand what you said, but this game has nothing to do with Fez, except it's inspired in it. My problem is that the "walking" animation looks strange.

Comment: Could you use a dark background so we can easily view the character on the webpage and also give a gif with the relevant frames so we can view the "weird animation" and not motionless images.

Comment: @Tiago - I just thought it was a programming error, that it wasn't playing back all the frames or something, so was looking for the code that does that. Am glad that the accepted answer is great :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regardless of the level of details and the number of pixels you have, you must start with a thorough understanding on how walking works.  If your character looks like shaking its legs, it probably because, that's all you drew : shaking its legs.

Just search "Walk cycle" with google image and you'll find plenty of examples.  Here is a little example of what I would do with yours, where the knee is green, the upper leg is yellow and the lower leg is orange.

[image]

It is of course improvable.

Comment: This example helped me a lot to understand the walk cycle. Thanks. :)